# terminal search files by text that the file names contain

Tags: terminal

Let's say there a file called "abc_deh.xyz", what command do i use to find the location of that file in mac terminal by using solely the search term "deh"?
So, basically, I am asking how to search for a file by text contained in its name. I need to find files that I forgot the whole name, that would be more helpful.

Answer (score 11):

```
sudo find / -type f -name "*deh*"
```

if you want to search directories too then remove the -type f.  You can also try:
    sudo locate *deh*

Should your locate database not be created (or up to date), there is a chance you have that file on the filesystem, but it's not been stored yet. Rather than run a single find command above, building the locate.db database might be a better plan going forward.

Answer (score 2):

The `mdfind` command can be used to find all indexed files that contain a specific string in the filename.

In your case:

```
 mdfind -name deh
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `glob-complete-word` a lot:

```
open */*deh # press \eg to complete paths
```

Also add `set show-all-if-ambiguous on` to `~/.inputrc` if you haven't already. If there are multiple completions, it makes the first press of `\eg` show all of them. If it's not enabled and there are multiple paths that match `*/*deh`, the `*deh` part is deleted.

If you use bash 4, `shopt -s globstar` makes `**` match multiple levels of directories.

If you use mdfind or find and there is a single line of output, you can use a key binding like this to insert it:

```
"\eo": "$(!!)\e\C-e"
```